# The translation for 'шаболда'

Tags: английский

What is the English equivalent for this word?

Comment: I see that Russian is your native language, so this question is off-topic, because, asking for translations to English is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0):

> 1. устар., жарг. то же, что шабалда; **болтун, врун, негодный человек**.
> 2. жарг., пренебр. **потаскуха, распутница** ◆ А мне все равно, что ты думала, шаболда ты пучеглазая! Владимир Колычев, «Постой, паровоз!», 2007 г. ◆ Мешки под глазами и ярко накрашенные губы красочно дополняли портрет этой привокзальной шаболды.

So, outdated meaning is "someone that talks too much, liar, worthless person" and second, derogatory one - "a slut".

Personally, I have never heard this word in speech.

Comment: I haven't ever heard this word, too. But "шалава" seems to be a more common word. I suggest to ask in "english language learners" group/forum for the proper translation, since there would be more native english speakers than here.

Comment: But they might not know Russian. Btw we often use it in speech.

Comment: Personally, I definitely heard this word quite a few times, but never the 1st meaning.

Comment: @Marat Yes, maybe шабалда и шалава are somehow connected.

Comment: @Artemix Now, this would be a nice question on its own (whether these two words are connected somehow)